# Excel VBA pastes modified value instead original one

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My macro below inserts value (Hello) into cell A1 and copies this value using copy method. Then it changes value in A1 (Hi).

At the end I would like to paste (original) value into another cell e.g. B1. 
I'm very surprised that Excel pastes modified value instead original one (why? copying has been before modifying!).

Notice: My macro starts with CopyAndPasteData().

```
Sub CopyAndPasteData()
  Range("A1") = "Hello"
  CopyData
  Range("A1") = "Hi"
  PasteData
End Sub

Sub CopyData()
  Range("A1").Copy
End Sub

Sub PasteData()
  Range("B1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be in three separate sections? Or could it be done all at once?

Comment: That would be because you are copying the cell itself and whatever modifications you make on the cell will be copied across to `Range("B1").pastespecial`. Can't you just paste first before changing the value of `Range(A1)`? Otherwise store the value of `Range("A1")` in a variable and then paste it on `Range("B1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub test()
    dim s as String
    Range("A1") = "Hello"
    s = Range("A1").value
    Range("B1").value = s
    PasteData
end sub
```

This is the best thing you can do. Create a variable and assign the value of A1 to the particular variable so that you can use the first value anywhere by accessing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this occurs is because the `.copy` method simply saves a reference to the copied cell, rather than saving its current attributes (i.e. the text and formatting).

It is only when `.paste` occurs that the copied cell's attributes are read and applied to the paste-cell.

That is why even though the `.copy` occurs before your changes, the changes are still reflected in `.paste`.

This isn't noticeable when using excel normally because as soon as you make a change to the spreadsheet the clipboard clears, so you don't have the chance to paste after changing a copied cell.

To back up this claim, if you add `Range("A1").Delete` before `PasteData` you'll get a runtime error because the `.copy` reference now points to an object that doesn't exist.